# conda UnsatisfiableError involving glibc?

Tags: conda, glibc

I want to use a program called `flexbar` in a conda environment:

`conda create -c bioconda -n test_env flexbar`

However the installation fails due to conflicts :

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: | 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.35=0
  - flexbar -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 2.35
```

I guess updating `glibc` is the answer ? However I can't find out how to proceed and since glibc is an kind of a system-thing I'm afraid to make some stupid mistakes ...

Here are the details of conda search -c bioconda flexbar --info :

```
flexbar 3.5.0 hf53871c_6
------------------------
file name   : flexbar-3.5.0-hf53871c_6.tar.bz2
name        : flexbar
version     : 3.5.0
build       : hf53871c_6
build number: 6
size        : 384 KB
license     : BSD-3-Clause
subdir      : linux-64
url         : https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/linux-64/flexbar-3.5.0-hf53871c_6.tar.bz2
md5         : e3dc22c8602b46de457db6242cd905f1
timestamp   : 2022-08-09 10:09:21 UTC
dependencies: 
  - bzip2 >=1.0.8,<2.0a0
  - libgcc-ng >=12
  - libstdcxx-ng >=12
  - libzlib >=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0
  - seqan-library
  - tbb >=2020.2,<2021.0.0a0
  - zlib >=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0
```

Thanks.

Comment: Bioconda requires Conda Forge.

Comment: "I guess updating glibc is the answer ?" -- if your installed GLIBC is 2.35 (which appears to be the case), updating it  is _not_ the answer -- it's already very new.